# What's the Spanish PP position on masks?

Tags: parties, covid-19, spain

The People's Party (PP) made [headlines](https://www.france24.com/en/europe/20210504-right-wing-anti-lockdown-leader-wins-madrid-s-snap-election) for winning a large share of votes the Madrid local election for their anti-lockdown stance.

I've also read [that](https://www.euractiv.com/section/coronavirus/news/spain-votes-to-end-obligatory-outdoor-face-mask-rule/):

> [The] Spanish parliament has approved a government decree of 26 June that ends the obligation to wear face masks outdoors when distancing is practicable. [...]
>
> The measure was passed despite some members of Congress advocating for a return to the face mask rule in all circumstances, as a fifth wave of coronavirus infections spreads across Europe. [...]
>
> The measure was backed by 180 MPs, with 90 voting against and 78 abstaining.
>
> The Socialist Party of Prime Minister Pedro Sánchez and junior left-wing partners Unidas Podemos both supported the measure, while the right-wing Popular Party opposed it and the far-right VOX abstained.

Why did the PP oppose the measure? Do they prefer "masks everywhere" or do they rather oppose even this level of mask wearing as in that June decree?

Comment: I just want to point out that, with the exception of a few national lockdowns last year, many of the anti-Covid measures have been decided at the regional level and there have been significant differences, even among governments of the same party. Specially within the PP, since while Ayuso (Madrid) was very vocal against all kind of restriction, for example Feijoo (Galicia) supported them.

Comment: Under Pablo Casado rule, the PP position on anything must be defined by Marxist principles. Not Karl, but Groucho's: *"these are my principles; if you don't like them... well, I have others"*. The PP position on masks can vary along the day, and it depends heavily on what opinion the socialist government has on them. If they support them, then the PP is against. Or otherwise. Or maybe even both things. Who knows.